# SerialPortError in QSerialPort 5.2?

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qt5

How can I use `SerialPortError` to get a human readable text in QSerialPort 5.2? The only thing I know is `error()` returns `enum`. I have the list of the errors in Qt documentation. I don't want to reinvent the wheel. For example, `1` indicates accessing to non existed port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QIODevice, the parent class of QSerialPort, has an errorString() method.  The [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qiodevice.html#errorString) states:

```
Returns a human-readable description of the last device error that occurred.
```

Unfortunately, a quick glance through the code reveals that QSerialPort does not set the error string when it sets the error code.  It looks like you will need to generate the error strings yourself.

errorString() may still return a valid error string if the error was set by QIODeivce instead of QSerialPort.

Comment: I've tried `errorString()` but as you said it gave no sense error. Thanks any way.